# How can I divert an event to a different target?

Tags: kotlin, javafx

I have a menu item that generates an Event. I want to listen to that event in a different Node, that is in a different "tree" of nodes than the menu item.

Is there any way I can divert the event, for example in an event filter in a common node in the scene graph?

Comment: @Abra I created a working solution using the event handler, but I'm wondering if I am misusing JavaFX events and should look for some kind of event bus library. I ran into this problem because I originally though all events were global and that you just subscribe and emit them.

Comment: What are you trying to use the events for?

Comment: take a step back and revisit your real requirement as @Slaw implicitly suggested - this might be a xy-problem.

Comment: “I want to listen to that event in a different Node”. This doesn’t really make sense. You don’t listen for events *in Nodes*. You listen for events by writing listeners and registering them with the node generating the event. That code typically exists in a controller, if you are using some kind of MVC-like pattern.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments I suspect that JavaFX events aren't meant to be used as an event bus mechanism. However, in order to answer the question, it can be done as follows.

Register a handler in the common node in the tree, then create a new event targeting the desired node that you want to divert to.

```
node.addEventHandler(CUSTOM_EVENT) {
    it.consume()
    Event.fireEvent(targetNode, CUSTOM_EVENT())
}
```

Comment: generally it's a bad idea to re-fire an event on receiving it (you are confusing the dispatch chain) - so don't. Anyway, this sounds like a xy-problem, best to take a step back and investigate the _real_ problem :)